# После компиляции трансляция?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

Изучаю WinApi, столкнулся в одной книге с таким описанием:

> Вместо этого оно (Windows-приложение) обращается к функциям GDI, GDI транслирует эти обращения к программным драйверам физических устройств, обеспечивая аппаратную независимость приложений.

И тут меня возник вопрос:

При компиляции C++ кода с применением WinApi мы получаем файлы .obj на языке ассемблера которые компонуются (так? не уверен что прав). Возможна  ли при этом трансляция?  Т.е. graphics device interface (GDI)(как я предполагаю набор структур и функций) выступает в роли аналога Java-машины, благодаря которой возможна трансляция в промежуточный байт-код?

Comment: слово "трансляция" тут имеет другой смысл :)

Comment: Смешались в кучу кони, люди... "GDI транслирует эти обращения к программным драйверам" вообще никакого отношения к компиляции не имеет. И ".obj на языке ассемблера" не бывает.

Comment: @PinkTux, как я правильно понял в `.obj` файлах содержится двоичный, так?

Comment: @СемёнШелухин почитайте тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C

Comment: @СемёнШелухин, бинарный код - это совсем не ассемблер

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никакого промежуточного байт-кода нет.
Имеется в виду "слоистая" структура программного обеспечения операционной системы. Приложение вызывает функции операционной системы - функции GDI, которые находятся в своих DLL, например, и которые уже обращаются к конкретному аппаратному обеспечению. Опять же, через еще один слой - драйверов.

Т.е., например, имеем стандартный оператор

```
fstream << "Hello, world";
```

Он внутри стандартной библиотеки обращается к функциям Windows, скорее всего к `WriteFile`. Соответствующий код этой функции в `Kernel32.dll` будет уже обращаться к конкретным драйверам - разобравшись, где и на каком носителе этот файл - к драйверам USB, диска или еще чего. Которые уже на аппаратном уровне будут выполнять запись.

Т.е. ваша программа не должна знать, **как** работать с тем или иным устройством - для этого есть иные слои программного обеспечения. И программа будет работать независимо от того, выполняется ли она на машине с SDD, обычным винтом или работает с сетевым файлом на другом конце света. В программе есть только обращение к функции в `Kernel32.dll`, и которого и близко нет в исходном тексте.

Так более-менее понятно?

Comment: Спасибо. То что я хотел.:-)

Answer (score 2):

В этой фразе

> Вместо этого оно (Windows-приложение) обращается к функциям GDI, GDI
>   транслирует эти обращения к программным драйверам физических
>   устройств, обеспечивая аппаратную независимость приложений

слово "транслирует" используется не в том смысле, как трансляция программ. Это означает, что делегирует конкретную работу по выполнению запроса драйверам физических устройств. То есть вводится промежуточный слой в виде Windows API, который является промежуточным интерфейсом между прикладной программой и физическими устройствами с их драйверами. Это позволяет прикладной программе не знать детали, что происходит на физическом уровне. Эти детали скрыты в Windows API, которое для приложений предоставляет общий интерфейс.